# What is the browser engine on Android devices?

Tags: browser

Different vendors send non-Chrome browsers by default. Can I assume all of them to be Chromimum based?

Answer (score 3):

No.

The default browser on stock Android is Google Chrome. This uses the [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_%28layout_engine%29) layout engine. For AOSP installations without the Google Apps, the default browser is the old "Browser" app that uses [Webkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit).

However, other browsers are available. [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) uses [Gecko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28software%29), [Opera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser) uses Blink, [Dolphin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) uses [Webkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit), and there are probably others. Additionally, I am informed in the comments that Samsung and HTC install different (non-Chrome) browsers on their phones. I do not know what they are, or what engine they use.

Summary: Android does not have a single browser or layout engine.

Comment: The default browser on Google Android is Chrome, the default browser on AOSP is the old 'Browser'. You are right, but there is a difference between 'Android' and 'Google Android', though it's a loose definition!

Comment: Then there's Samsung's default browser for Android, HTC's default one and so on. The fragmentation of Android makes this an absolute pain. +1 for the answer though!

Comment: @rossC thanks, I hadn't considered AOSP. And I wasn't aware that Samsung and HTC replace Chrome... the last time I had an HTC phone, Chrome wasn't available for Android anyway!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. If you want a more specific answer than that, you need to give more details on what you're trying to achieve, but bear in mind that programming questions are off-topic on this site.